# Can you use a property without a field in C#?

Tags: c#, properties, field

In C#, can you use a property without a field?

Edit for clarification:

```
private string _name;

public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set { _name value; }
}
```

It seem's like they are always paired, is there a circumstance where we don't use the field at all?

Comment: Sure, some properties are deserts, marshland, etc. You can use a piece of property even if it doesn't have a field in it. Joking aside, I'm not sure what you're asking, can you elaborate?

Comment: sure, I'll edit the main

Comment: If it just returns a constant, there is no field, for example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All properties must have a field, assuming they are simple properties to store a value (*). However, the language ([as of version 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)) offers a way to declare the field implicitly. For example:

```
public int Value { get; set; }
```

That would declare a property named `Value` with an implicit field backing it and the getter and setter both public. You can include an accessibility keyword on either the getter or setter to restrict access to the property. For example:

```
public int Value { get; private set; }
```

In this case, only the owning type may call the setter, but any class can call the getter.

The next version of C# will have additional features for dealing with these "automatic properties", allowing you to provide a concise initialization syntax for them. For now, you have to initialize them in a constructor.

**EDIT:** based on your edited question, it seems worthwhile to address this specific question: "is there a circumstance where we don't use the field at all?"

The answer to that is, it's not common for *no* field to be involved at all. But it is possible, and it's not *uncommon* for a property to not use a field as storage for the property. For example, imagine a `Rectangle` object with an `Area` property:

```
class Rectangle
{
    public double Width { get; private set; }
    public double Height { get; private set; }
    public double Area { get { return Width * Height; } }
}
```

Obviously there are fields involved (two of them), but there is not a field specifically dedicated to the `Area` property.

Another example would be where the property delegates. For example, in a WinForms `Form` subclass, it's common to expose specific control values via a property:

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    public string EditText
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text; }
        set { textBox1.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

Again, the `textBox1` field is being used here. But it actually represents something other than the property itself. The property is using a member of the object that field references.

I hope that clarifies the relationship between fields and properties adequately for you. Please feel free to ask for further clarifications if needed.

(*) Note that the only real rule for properties is that they have at least one of the getter or setter, and those methods can do whatever you want. I assume we are talking about simple value-based properties here.

Comment: thanks for the clarification... so if I understand you correctly there is ALWAYS a field, it's just not always explicitly defined. In the case of an auto-property the C# compiler automatically adds the field?

Comment: I think is an extremely confusing way to word the answer to this question. A property does not require a field in any way. With automatically implemented properties, the compiler generates a field.

Comment: @mike z I suppose it depends on how the question was phrased. If it were "Do I need to include a field with a property" its No and if the question were "Does every property have a field" the the answer would be yes. Unfortunately, my question wasn't quite as clear.

Comment: @dbeaulieu But the answer to that second question is also 'No'.

Comment: @mike z, I was under the impression that the answer was yes because in the case of an auto-property the C# compiler will infer a field implicitly??? This is wrong?

Comment: @dbeaulieu: yes, there's always a field for simple value-based properties. Please note the qualifying statement that introduces my answer: we are talking _strictly_ of "simple properties to store a value" here. As mike correctly restates (I did already state this in my answer), a field is not actually required for properties. A getter simply has to return a value, which can come from anywhere. Likewise, a setter will be passed a value, but the setter need not actually do anything at all with it, never mind specifically store it in a field.

Comment: @mikez: I believe I covered this already in my answer, that the requirement for a field is not from the language, but simply a characteristic of "simple properties to store a value". But if you have a suggestion for an alternate wording that you think would be more clear, I'm more than happy to consider it.

Comment: It might be helpful to note that auto properties were introduced in C# 3.0; prior to that you must define backing variables for getters and setters.

Answer (score 2):

A property is not required to have a field

```
public string Version
{
    get
    {
      return "1.3.Awesome";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think even in this instance, there is an implicit field that is being generated behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking what I think you are, the answer is yes, you just put get; set; inside the property declaration. C# encapsulates a variable for you.

EDIT: example

```
//no need for field declaration
public string Name
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Comment: doesn't the property use the field for return (get) and value (set)?

Comment: @dbeaulieu it uses a field that it creates internally, you don't' have to create it.